# Guardar elementos de pago CFDI en c#

Tags: c#, xml

Tengo un XML CFDI versión 3.3 y quiero guardar los atributos del nodo DoctoRelacionado. Me funciona guardar los atributos del primer nodo, el problema es que en algunos XML me vienen mas de 1 nodo DoctoRelacionado y sólo guarda el primero. Como hago para guardar los n nodos que vengan?

Como pueden ver, en lo que esta comentado intenté hacer lo siguiente:

1. Guardar los atributos del primer nodo DoctoRelacionado. HECHO.
2. Preguntar si hay un segundo nodo. HECHO.
3. Eliminar el primer nodo DoctoRelacionado para que mi segundo nodo se convierta en mi primer nodo y asi hacerlo n veces.

Pero no resultó, creo que tengo que hacer un foreach o algo asi, pero en realidad no se como. Agradezco su ayuda.

**Aquí mi método:**

```
private bool cargar_Complementos(ref Factura factura, string xml)
    {       
        try
        {
            XNamespace cfdi = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3";
            XNamespace tfd = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital";
            XNamespace bfa2 = "http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/addenda/bf/2";
            XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
            XNamespace pago10 = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/Pagos";

            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            Comprobante = xdoc.Element(cfdi.GetName("Comprobante"));

            Fecha = Convert.ToString(Comprobante.Attribute("Fecha").Value);
            Folio = Convert.ToString(Comprobante.Attribute("Folio").Value);
            Serie = Convert.ToString(Comprobante.Attribute("Serie").Value);

            Complemento = Comprobante.Element(cfdi.GetName("Complemento"));

            Pagos = Complemento.Element(pago10.GetName("Pagos"));

            Pago = Pagos.Element(pago10.GetName("Pago"));
            Pago = Pagos.Element(pago10.GetName("Pago"));

            DoctoRelacionado = Pago.Element(pago10.GetName("DoctoRelacionado"));

            //if (contador != 0)
            //{
            //    int aux = contador;
            //    while (aux != 0)
            //    {
            //        DoctoRelacionado.Remove();
            //        aux--;
            //    }

            //}

            ImpPagado = Convert.ToDecimal((DoctoRelacionado.Attribute("ImpPagado").Value));
            IdDocumento = Convert.ToString((DoctoRelacionado.Attribute("IdDocumento").Value));
            TimbreFiscalDigital = Complemento.Element(tfd.GetName("TimbreFiscalDigital"));
            UUID = Convert.ToString((TimbreFiscalDigital.Attribute("UUID").Value));

            //contador++;

            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Aquí mi XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:xsi="" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" Version="3.3" Serie="VRI" Folio="21511" Fecha="2017-12-14T11:40:01" NoCertificado="" SubTotal="0" Moneda="XXX" Total="0" TipoDeComprobante="P" LugarExpedicion="" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd" Sello="/+Oi472PgRD/tVkMw==" Certificado="+/=">
  <cfdi:Emisor Rfc="" Nombre=""/>
  <cfdi:Receptor Rfc="" Nombre="" UsoCFDI=""/>
  <cfdi:Conceptos>
    <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="" Cantidad="1" ClaveUnidad="ACT" Descripcion="Pago" ValorUnitario="0" Importe="0"/>
  </cfdi:Conceptos>
  <cfdi:Complemento>
    <pago10:Pagos xmlns:pago10="http://www.sat.gob.mx/Pagos" Version="1.0">
      <pago10:Pago FechaPago="2017-12-14T11:44:47" FormaDePagoP="03" MonedaP="MXN" Monto="7951.13">
        <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="3AC5077C-41D1-8C4B-" Serie="VSRI" Folio="86707" MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD" NumParcialidad="1" ImpSaldoAnt="5044.04" ImpPagado="5044.04" ImpSaldoInsoluto="0.00"/>
        <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="-2D1E-4B58-825D-" Serie="VSRI" Folio="86708" MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD" NumParcialidad="1" ImpSaldoAnt="2907.09" ImpPagado="2907.09" ImpSaldoInsoluto="0.00"/>
      </pago10:Pago>
    </pago10:Pagos><tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital Version="1.1" UUID="-B806-4BE5-A0D8-9E8202A6BEB4" FechaTimbrado=":44:58" RfcProvCertif="FEL100622S88" SelloCFD="DDAF70qWqmYPFBfcP8R1Ph8EzMQTV8o1XCEmfQ/uh+PVb/xVj14HVnVwMxWnP0yyPU/D/tVkMw==" NoCertificadoSAT="" xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital"  SelloSAT="/J8A==" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigitalv11.xsd"  />
  </cfdi:Complemento>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si exactamente.

Al hacer element, solamente estas obteniendo el primero que encuentra.

En realidad estas buscando el metodo Elements, el cual devuelve una coleccion de los hijos de ese elemento.

Por lo tanto, podrías hacer algo como

```
foreach(var v in Pago.Elements(pago10.GetName("DoctoRelacionado")))
{
    //tu codigo aca
}
```

Comment: Algo en mi código debe estar mal, usé este foreach y me trae 2 veces los mismos valores. En "impPagado" la primera vez debe traerme: 5044 y la segunda 2907, pero las dos veces me trae 5044.

Comment: no se como escribiste lo de adentro, pero ya avanzaste un paso.. trajo dos cosas ;).. probaste depurar tu codigo a ver que hace en cada vuelta?

Comment: Si, ya lo depuré, pero me entra duda en si debo dejar mi variable DoctoRelacionado = Pago.Element(pago10.GetName("DoctoRelacionado")); o esto ya lo quito? En cuanto a lo de adentro, le puse esto: ImpPagado = Convert.ToDecimal((DoctoRelacionado.Attribute("ImpPagado").Value));
IdDocumento = Convert.ToString((DoctoRelacionado.Attribute("IdDocumento").Value));
TimbreFiscalDigital = Complemento.Element(tfd.GetName("TimbreFiscalDigital"));
UUID = Convert.ToString((TimbreFiscalDigital.Attribute("UUID").Value));

Comment: obviamente tu codigo de adentro esta totalmente incorrecto. Tenes que quitar la busqueda a un solo elemento (ahora vas a recorrer la collecion que devuelve) y tenes que usar v como elemento dentro del for. y de paso, fijate que hace elements, y como funciona foreach.

Comment: Ya me funcionó!!! En efecto, no había acomodado bien lo que estaba dentro del foreach. Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Hola prueba con esto:

```
  //variables del esquema
  XNamespace cfdi = @"http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3";
  XNamespace tfd = @"http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital";
  XNamespace pago10 = @"http://www.sat.gob.mx/Pagos";

 //cargamos el xml
 var xdoc = XDocument.Load(Vars.rutaXML);


foreach (var v in xdoc.Element(cfdi + "Comprobante").Element(cfdi + "Complemento").Element(pago10 + "Pagos").Elements(pago10 + "DoctoRelacionado "))
{
   string x1 = (string)v.Attribute("IdDocumento");  
}
```

Comment: Por favor explica lo que hace el código que dices que pruebe. Puedes leer [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) cómo guía.